# Connectivity between two site to site VPN connections connected to Azure VPN gateway

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

We have an azure VPN gateway setup with two site-to-site connections that are successfully configured. Site A (local network gateway A) and Site B (local network gateway B) can each see everything in the azure VNET where the VPN gateway resides.

We cannot, however, see resources between our sites.  For example, I cannot RDP to a machine from my local network gateway A to a machine in local network gateway B even though both local network gateways are connected to the Azure VPN gateway.  Both sites (A and B) have added static routes to ensure our respective routers forward requests through the VPN tunnel for our respective local gateway address spaces.

Is this type of connectivity turned off by default for security reasons or should it work with default settings?

Comment: If you follow the document [Add a Site-to-Site connection to a VNet with an existing VPN gateway connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-multi-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal)?

Comment: Well yea...that's how I got both site to site connections up and running.  Each site can see everything inside azure but they cannot see each other.  Maybe I didn't clarify the question.  A = on premise site A.  B = on premise site B.  C = Azure VNET and all resources in that VNET.  A can see C because of site to site.  B can see C because of site to site.  A CANNOT see B.  Maybe that better explains it?  I'm wondering if this is by design or if route entries can be made to forward traffic between the two local network gateways that are attached to the VNET via Site-to-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible only with a Route Based VPN, and [will work best with BGP Enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-bgp-overview). You might also need to create custom routes on your on-prem devices so that traffic destined for your other on-prem network will go to the azure gateway.

Comment: Great, so at least we know this configuration is supported.  We had already added static entries in our respective on-premise routes to ensure traffic destined to the other on-prem used the VPN gateway.  Before going down the BGP route, what is needed to enable the transit routing in Azure (I'm assuming this is the missing piece)?  Typically I saw those options available when doing VNET peering, but that doesn't seem to apply here.  Are you saying that this configuration is ONLY possible with BGP or is there a way to enable the transit routing in Azure without peering using VPN static routes?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can not connect with site A to site B.

[image]

> As shown in the diagram, the Azure VPN gateway has traffic selectors
>   from the virtual network to each of the on-premises network prefixes,
>   but not the cross-connection prefixes. For example, on-premises site
>   2, site 3, and site 4 can each communicate to VNet1 respectively, but
>   cannot connect via the Azure VPN gateway to each other. The diagram
>   shows the cross-connect traffic selectors that are not available in
>   the Azure VPN gateway under this configuration.

For more details, see [Connect Azure VPN gateways to multiple on-premises policy-based VPN devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-multiple-policybased-rm-ps).

Comment: This seems to be applicable for configuring multi-site with policy based VPN.  We use route based VPN configuration so are you sure this still applies to route based VPN gateways?

Comment: @Geekn The VPN on Azure is the route based, but the VPN on-premise is the policy based. Are your VPN all route based?

Comment: Yes our site to site connections to Azure are all configured via route based VTI.  My take on that article was primarily how to configure multiple site-to-site connections with policy based VPN which was previously restricted to 1 site-to-site.  That is not our setup.  We use route based connections for everything and cannot get clarification on whether our desired behavior is supported from the defaults or whether we need to create entries in an azure route table to support our connectivity between multiple on-premise sites.