# Azure Cross-region VNet connectivity with on-premises access

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have one Vnet (VNet1) in region 1 which is connected to on-premises using s2s VPN. I have got this peered with a second Vnet (Vnet2) in the same region following hub-spoke network pattern. VNet2 is configured to use Vnet1 Gateway transit for on-premises connectivity.

Now I have a third Vnet (Vnet3) in region3 which is also a spoke for Vnet1. Since this is in a different region I used VNet-VNet VPN (since Global Vnet peering doesn't support transitive gateway.) I reused the existing VPN that was used for S2S on Vnet1 for the Vnet1-Vnet3 connectivity.

The question is how do I support transit Gateway feature from VNet3->Vnet1 to achieve on-premises connectivity? To test it out I have setup UDR to route all traffic from Vnet3 to VPN Gateway. So this should bring the traffic to Vnet1. But this doesn't allow me to reach on-premises. Shouldn't Vnet1 routes know that the traffic is for on-premises and route it accordingly? Do I need some kind of NVA in Vnet1?

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multi VPNs between the vnets, first you should take care and pay attention to the limitations of it. See [limitations for multi VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-multi-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal#before). And you also can follow the steps to create the multi VPNs.

Comment: Thanks @Charles, I have already considered the limitations which is fine for now. I had already created the [S2S VPN] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) and then created [VNet-VNet VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal). Are you saying I have to do the other way round, because the link you shared assumes the VNet-Vnet VPN is already set up? Since a lot of effort has gone into the setup of the S2S VPN I cannot afford to tear it down - any alternatives?

Comment: If the VPN between Vnet1 and Vnet3 use the same gatewaysubnet in the Vnet1? Also does the VPN between Vnet1 and on-premise?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question clearly. Since I am using the same VNet1 VPN gateway for both S2S and Vnet-Vnet I suppose the two connections should use the same Gateway Subnet I suppose. Is there anyway to check? The new connectivity is between VNet1 and Vnet3. The VNet1-Onpremise VPN already exists and is working fine. I am trying to reuse the same Gateway used for Vnet1-On-premise for Vnet1-Vnet3 connection. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: When you create the connectivity Vnet1-Vnet3, you should make the Vnet3 as the on-permise, do you?

Comment: I have added an image to my original post to make it easier to understand. The area in Gray is pre-existing - I have VNet1 connected to On-premise using S2S VPN. I have Vnet2 peered to Vnet1 with gateway transit enabled so it can access on-premise. Now I want to add a new Vnet3 (shown in yellow) which is in region2 to the Vnet1 Hub so Vnet3 can access on-premise through the pre-existing Vnet1 gateway as well as access shared services like ADDS in Vnet1. However I cannot access on-premise resource from Vnet3. I can however access Vnet1 resources from VNet3 which is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand what you want. You can take a look at another [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903183/connectivity-between-two-site-to-site-vpn-connections-connected-to-azure-vpn-gat/51961978#51961978). It's similar to yours. Look the Vnet3 as another on-premise network.

Comment: Well it suggests that in their case it could be possible using Route based VPNs and using static routes to reach the destination network that uses the Gateway. We are using Route based gateway - so it would seem as per your answer that we might not be getting the routes correctly? The question is if I followed the [Multi-site VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-multi-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) where Vnet-Vnet VPn is setup before S2S then things are handled automatically. If I do the other way things don't work by default. Is this a limitation?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's the reason. You can have another try for it. As I know the vnet created with a default route, it may be overridden if you create one.

Answer (score 0):

Vnet-to-Vnet it will not work by itself the way you intend. Because when you create a V2V connection the routes between only the 2 vnets are created but not visible, so you can not edit them to add add the route to OnPrem also. That's why you were not able to connect directly from OnPrem to second Vnet.You can try to activate BGP on each connection S2S and V2V, this will take care of the routes.

If enabling BGP is not an option, then instead of using V2V between the 2 VNETs, use also S2S, check this article [here](https://medium.com/@andragabr/connect-from-onprem-to-azure-vnets-across-subscriptions-1b89306d15ef) second scenario the last part.